# Simple Products not Tied to Parent Configurable Product

Tags: configurable-product

I created a configurable product and neglected to check off "main website" for it, I then proceeded to create associated simple products, but this product didn't show up in its categories. I then added the configurable product to "main website", and then created more associated simple products which resulted in the product showing up in categories. I can't figure out how to get those simple products I created before adding the configurable product to "main website" to show up on the front end. I went through them all and added them to the same website, and made sure they have inventory, and cleared the cache and indexes. Any idea what I'm missing to make them show up on the frontend?

Any insight is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If a product doesn't show on frontend, you should check the following:
- Status (should be enabled)
- Visibility (should be Catalog or Catalog, Search)
- Category association
- Website association
- Inventory (qty and Stock Availability)

If all these are configured correctly, and products still don't show up, you should check if you have installed a custom module that may affect product visibility on catalog pages.

Comment: To clarify: the configurable product started showing up after I checked off "main website" under the websites tab, but the associated simple products did not. However, new associated simple products did show up.

Answer (score 2):

I take it that your visibility is set to catalogue as by default simple products that are associated with a configurable product will be set to NOT VISIBLE INDIVIDUALLY